# Azure MySQL db access denied

Tags: mysql, azure, mysql-workbench

I noticed lots of questions like this, but really can't understand anything in their "answers".

Btw, previous db's never met this problem.

Firstly, what i did.

1. Rebooted MySQL Workbench
2. Tried new database.
3. Queries:

   ```
   SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
   ```

and

```
    SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

returned

```
b4eae60edf28c3@xx.xxx.xx.xx  |  b4eae60edf28c3@%
```

and

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'b4eae60edf28c3'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 4
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO \'b4eae60edf28c3\'@\'%\''
```

so, as i see i have all the permissions.

4. People advicing to mess with root-access, but azure, as i understand, doesn't provide them. (i saw that somehow said that "root"/"bitnami" should work, but it didn't)
5. Also someone offers to work with mysql shell, but seems i don't have it.
6. Database is empty, so there is no memory excess.

I really noticed that this question is 100500th repeat, but i really didn't found anything in their answers. For example, i checked all questions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1044?sort=newest&pageSize=15.

May be my English skill doesn't allow me to understand them properly.

Excuse me once again and thank you for any guidance.

---

UPD:
I've found following answer:

> The correct answer is that ClearDB does not allow certain functionality on multi-tenant cluster, including create database, views, UDF's and triggers.
>   You would need to upgrade to a dedicated cluster in order to perform this statement.

But google query "azure upgrade to a dedicated cluster" didn't show anything suitable.

Comment: Since you solved your issue, please post a proper answer and mark it as such, so that this question may be properly closed.

Comment: It's not a solution(*for now), i just said that i found something similar but it didn't help.